# How to create a redirect for specific domain?

Tags: redirection, domain-access

I'm using [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) and [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) modules. Both work well.

But Redirect module only allows me to create redirects from relative path which affects as follows all my domains.

So how to create domain-specific redirect?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [Domain Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_redirect) module.

> This module allows the creation of an internal Drupal path that will
>   direct the user to a unique path based on the domain that the user is
>   in. The link is based at the path "/domain-redirect/12345" where
>   "12345" is the redirect ID that is stored in the database.

**OR**

Try to use [Domain Default Redirection](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_default_redirect) module.

> This small module provides a redirection feature instead of providing
>   the default domain contents in the Domain Access suite.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform multisite redirect by using [Multisite Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/multisite_redirect) module.

> Multisite Redirect is a system designed to allow users to create and
>   manage URL redirects across domains in a sort of multisite
>   configuration. The primary use case for this module is one where a
>   client might have multiple domains that are being consolidated into a
>   single site.